# csvsimple - process column names with digits correctly

Tags: tables, csv, csvsimple

I have a csv that contains column names with digits. Somehow this seems to be a problem for csvsimple, but I can't quite figure out why and how to deal with it correctly.

Here's what I want to achieve:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{ndcgs.csv}
system;ndcg5;ndcg10;ndcg15;ndcg20;ndcg30;ndcg100;ndcg200;ndcg500;ndcg1000
A;0.632;0.566;0.531;0.533;0.511;0.475;0.396;0.301;0.301
B;0.646;0.615;0.598;0.588;0.563;0.536;0.517;0.401;0.363
C;0.557;0.567;0.589;0.576;0.573;0.511;0.478;0.429;0.380
D;0.644;0.577;0.538;0.540;0.518;0.473;0.398;0.303;0.302
E;0.291;0.304;0.302;0.330;0.351;0.361;0.281;0.238;0.236
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\csvstyle{myTableStyle}{tabular=lc,
table head=\toprule system & ndcg5\\\midrule,
table foot=\bottomrule,
head to column names,
separator=semicolon}

\csvreader[myTableStyle]{ndcgs.csv}{}%
    {\system & \ndcg5}

\end{document}
```

The error message complains about an undefined control sequence, related to the column name "ndcg5":

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\csv@tablehead ->\toprule 
                      system & ndcg5\\\midrule 
l.25         {\system & \ndcg5}
```

I tried to prevent this by using `\csvcolii` etc but still the same error.

I found that the following works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{ndcgs.csv}
system;ndcg5;ndcg10;ndcg15;ndcg20;ndcg30;ndcg100;ndcg200;ndcg500;ndcg1000
A;0.632;0.566;0.531;0.533;0.511;0.475;0.396;0.301;0.301
B;0.646;0.615;0.598;0.588;0.563;0.536;0.517;0.401;0.363
C;0.557;0.567;0.589;0.576;0.573;0.511;0.478;0.429;0.380
D;0.644;0.577;0.538;0.540;0.518;0.473;0.398;0.303;0.302
E;0.291;0.304;0.302;0.330;0.351;0.361;0.281;0.238;0.236
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lc}%
\bfseries system & \bfseries ndcg-5%
    \csvreader[separator=semicolon]{ndcgs.csv}{}%
     {\\ \csvcoli & \csvcolii}%
 \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

But I don't see how this approach would allow me to define the table layout (regarding toprule, midrule etc.) in the same way as in the example above.

Can anyone help?

Comment: "I tried to prevent this by using \csvcolii etc but still the same error." -> To be more precise, I can press enter a few times when the error appears in this case and at some point, the pdf finally gets generated, but this is not really helpful when using make tools like arara.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use names with numbers as a macro to indicate the column names simply because you can't use numbers in TeX macros, see here: https://texfaq.org/FAQ-linmacnames.

Your problem, however, is easily solvable with `\csvcoli...`, two examples follow.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{ndcgs.csv}
system;ndcg5;ndcg10;ndcg15;ndcg20;ndcg30;ndcg100;ndcg200;ndcg500;ndcg1000
A;0.632;0.566;0.531;0.533;0.511;0.475;0.396;0.301;0.301
B;0.646;0.615;0.598;0.588;0.563;0.536;0.517;0.401;0.363
C;0.557;0.567;0.589;0.576;0.573;0.511;0.478;0.429;0.380
D;0.644;0.577;0.538;0.540;0.518;0.473;0.398;0.303;0.302
E;0.291;0.304;0.302;0.330;0.351;0.361;0.281;0.238;0.236
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

First method, table formatting as \verb|\csvreader| options:

\csvstyle{myTableStyle}{tabular=lc,
table head=\toprule \bfseries system & \bfseries ndcg-5\\\midrule,
table foot=\bottomrule,
head to column names,
separator=semicolon}
\begin{center}
\csvreader[myTableStyle]{ndcgs.csv}{}%
    {\csvcoli & \csvcolii}
\end{center}    

Second method, \verb|tabular| with a \verb|\csvreader| inside:

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lc}
\toprule
\bfseries system & \bfseries ndcg-5 \\
\midrule\csvreader[separator=semicolon, late after line=\\]{ndcgs.csv}{}%
     {\csvcoli & \csvcolii}
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. As I said in the comment, I already tried to use `\csvcoli...` and also got the "Undefined control sequence" error. Comparing with your example I saw that you also imported the booktabs package which I didn't. After importing it, it works.

Comment: @codebat Yes, your error probably was only that!

Comment: Sometimes it's the small things... But I also learned through your second example how to achieve the table layout I wanted in this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible to do this: you just need to use `\csuse` from the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{filecontents*}{ndcgs.csv}
system;ndcg5;ndcg10;ndcg15;ndcg20;ndcg30;ndcg100;ndcg200;ndcg500;ndcg1000
A;0.632;0.566;0.531;0.533;0.511;0.475;0.396;0.301;0.301
B;0.646;0.615;0.598;0.588;0.563;0.536;0.517;0.401;0.363
C;0.557;0.567;0.589;0.576;0.573;0.511;0.478;0.429;0.380
D;0.644;0.577;0.538;0.540;0.518;0.473;0.398;0.303;0.302
E;0.291;0.304;0.302;0.330;0.351;0.361;0.281;0.238;0.236
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\csvstyle{myTableStyle}{tabular=lc,
table head=\toprule system & ndcg5\\\midrule,
table foot=\bottomrule,
head to column names,
separator=semicolon}

\csvreader[myTableStyle]{ndcgs.csv}{}%
{\system & \csuse{ndcg5}}

\end{document}
```

to produce:

[image]